# Dependent drop down in google forms

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible, in google forms, to have a drop down list dependent on the answer given in the previous answer? For example, in the first question they say one country and in the second question they only have cities of that country

Comment: You have to have a pre-made form. So, use the "go to page based on answer" functionality, and send them to a pre-made page based on the input. If you are using a web-app, you could manage this entirely on your end, by showing your own custom form pages, and at the end, filling the answers into the actual Google Form to submit it.

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms doesn't include a way to do that. The alternative is to build your own web form. You could use the HTML Service of Google Apps Script to do it.